# Is this IC a BJT?

Tags: integrated-circuit, bjt

I have a unknown 3 terminal IC in a SOT23 style package. I think it may be a BJT but I am a bit puzzled by the results of probing a DMM across all the terminals in diode mode. Below is a figure of the IC with a table of the DMM measurements.

[image]

[image]

I also set up a test to see if it behaves like a BJT. It does in fact behave like an NPN BJT with PIN1 = collector, PIN2 = base, and PIN3 = emitter.

Below is a diagram of the test circuit:
[image]

Is it possible for a BJT to have a third diode drop from the emitter to collector (Pin3 to Pin1)? Is it some sort of ESD protection diode? If not, what else could this three terminal device be?

Comment: Some BTJs have resistors inside package.

Comment: A resistor in series with base or a darlington pair still wouldn't explain two 1.7V diode drops though or the fact that there is a 3rd diode drop. That would only explain one higher diode drop from base to emitter. My IC has two 1.7V diode drops and a 1.48V diode drop.

Comment: Can you add a photo of the device?

Comment: Also, a resistor across two of the terminals would show up bidirectionally (ie. the orientation of the probes wouldn't matter). However, the 1.48V diode drop is not bidirectional. It's open in the other direction

Comment: Asking me to upload a photo made me look at the marking on top - there is a '121'.  After a quick google search with '121 BJT', it looks like this might be the part https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip120-d.pdf

Comment: If this is the IC, why would the base to emitter diode drop and the base to collector diode drop both be 1.7V. Wouldn't the base to emitter be around 1/2 of the base to collector?

Comment: there's LDOs in that package, including 1.8V as relatively common voltage

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Yes, several possibilities according to this table, but LDO would be the most likely. https://smd.yooneed.one/code3132.html

Comment: Not a TIP121, this transistor is always in a large package.